# How to build faceted search with facet counters using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to build a facet search with counters like below[image]

But using the documentations of [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

I'm not able to reach the output as I want. anyone can help me out of it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rahul I would have tried GET countries/_search
{
    
   "aggregations": {
      "all_countries": {
         "global": {},
         "aggregations": {
            "countries": {
               "terms": {"field": "contries"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

Comment: It would help if you could also provide your schema. However, "field": "contries" countries seems to be misspelled. Please check if it is desired

Comment: @Rahul schema in the sense what are the things you want to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refer this:-**
[this might work!!!!](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html)